# Making ice cream at home without a machine

Tags: ice-cream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make ice cream made without a machine?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/how-to-make-ice-cream-made-without-a-machine)

I need an method for making ice cream at home, without access to an ice cream machine.