# How to make creamier and softer vegan coconut ice-cream?

Tags: freezing, dessert, ice-cream, coconut

I was making vegan coconut ice-cream with coconut milk base. Instead of using [a can of coconut milk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0046HCSV2), shredded coconut with hot water was squeezed through a towel for coconut milk replacement. Then almond milk added and whisked together before putting in the back of the refrigerator (no ice cream maker). Ice cream is really hard and icy after one night. Is it possible to make creamy and soft coconut ice cream with coconut milk from shredded coconut or coconut flesh?

Comment: Did you churn/whisk it as it was freezing? By this I mean: Put in freezer, wait 10 min, remove from freezer and whisk, return to freezer. Repeat until frozen. Also did you add any sugar to your mix?

Comment: Doug is correct, any ice cream base will freeze into a solid block if simply left to freeze. It has to be agitated. Your question sounds like you didn't do this, but maybe this is just an unlucky wording.

Comment: The homemade coconut milk may have a lower fat content than canned, which affects the consistency.

Comment: @Doug I did put in the freezer and add sugar. Maybe this is just a mistake while doing. I wilk try again.

Comment: @Erica Can you explain more about the consistency with the homemade coconut milk? Thanks.

Comment: @Siena it's conjecture on my part: If the coconut is not pulped in a blender before straining there might be less coconut oil. Hard to find numbers for this, although [this site](http://cookforgood.com/blog/2012/10/3/homemade-coconut-milk-vs-coconut-dream-coconut-drink-smackdo.html) says 10g fat in 1 cup of homemade (pureed) coconut milk, and [this site](http://www.calorieking.com/foods/calories-in-nut-drinks-coconut-milk-premium-canned_f-ZmlkPTgxMzkz.html) says 40g fat in 8 fl oz. canned coconut milk. I think that the stirring (to incorporate air) is also important, though.

Comment: Coconut milk from a can is both the pulp and the water mixed, whereas the OP has made it just from pulp + water. I think the main source of fat is really only from the almond milk.

Comment: Any egg substitute in there like Soy lecithin?

Answer (score 2):

As you froze the base without agitating it, larger ice crystals would have formed.

If you have a food processor, you may be able to rescue it by cutting it into chunks (to fit in the food processor), then whizzing it around 'til it's more like a smoothie, then re-freezing it.

If you don't have a food processor, you might be able to let it thaw completely, then re-freeze it, making sure to agitate it multiple times in the process.  One easy way to do it i to put it in a heavy zip-top bag, then a second one (double bagging it), then you can just shake & squish it around every so often while it re-freezes.

Comment: Also see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/how-to-make-ice-cream-without-a-machine for a list of ways of freezing ice cream when you don't have a machine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a cornstarch base to help thicken the mixture might help. Also the advice about taking it and whisking is very important.